# How do I disable news polling in eclipse for all workspaces in one shot?

Tags: eclipse

I'm working in eclipse and have many workspaces. I have to fine-tune each workspace, disabling annoying news popup. I use eclipse as an IDE, I have another applications to read news.

Is there a way to propagate the disabled news polling into all workspaces? Or have this setting global?

Comment: What news popup? This isn't part of core Eclipse

Comment: Hi greg, I'm referring to News RSS aggregator in eclipse, which is configured in "Preferences / General / News". Isn't it in a core?

Comment: No, it isn't. It may be in one of the larger packages but I've never heard of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A radical option is to completely remove the plugin that provides a news feed.

1. Go to <kbd>Help</kbd> > <kbd>About Eclipse IDE</kbd> > <kbd>Installation Details</kbd> and uninstall "Code Recommenders News Feed".
2. Restart Eclipse.
3. When the following window pops up, check "Remember my decision" and click <kbd>Skip</kbd>.

**Update:** It looks like the "Remember by decision" checkbox is per-workspace, and not global.

[image: Eclipse Requirements Update]

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find a central setting but what I ended up doing is have a template workspace with default preferences (news disabled, dark theme etc.) and inherit from that.

So when I start a new project I open my default workspace, then go 
to <kbd>File</kbd> → <kbd>Switch Workspace</kbd> → <kbd>Other...</kbd>.
In the workspace I browse to where I want my new workspace to be (usually I have a master workspace and a bunch of sub-workspaces) and I make sure I check <kbd>Copy Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Preferences</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the news polling at: Window > Preferences > General > News.

Uncheck the the checkbox "Enable automatic news polling".
[Screenshot with the settings panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5KLM.png)

Comment: This is a per-workspace setting, and not a global setting.

Comment: it doesn't answer the question